# Modifying object(s) from Raphael.js

Tags: javascript, dom, raphael

If I have a item like http://raphaeljs.com/ball.html, how can I modify it via DOM, to change the color of a specific instance?

EX:

```
Raphael.fn.ball = function (x, y, r, hue) {
        hue = hue || 0;
        return this.set(
            this.ellipse(x, y + r - r / 5, r, r / 2).attr({fill: "rhsb(" + hue + ", 1, .25)-hsb(" + hue + ", 1, .25)", stroke: "none", opacity: 0}),
            this.ellipse(x, y, r, r).attr({fill: "r(.5,.9)hsb(" + hue + ", 1, .75)-hsb(" + hue + ", .5, .25)", stroke: "none"}),
            this.ellipse(x, y, r - r / 5, r - r / 20).attr({stroke: "none", fill: "r(.5,.1)#ccc-#ccc", opacity: 0})
        );
    };

function drawBall(div_id, color) {
        var X = Raphael(div_id), x = 100, y = 80, r = 50;
        X.ball(x, y, r, color);
    }
```

I do create a "Ball" (document.write(active_div, 0.3459912) in the document, and now I want to change the color.

Calling drawBall with the same div, just creates another "ball" in the DIV.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var hue = hue;  
X.attr("fill", r(.3,.25) white-" + hue);
```

You can use any color like `yellow` or color code like `#00CC33` for hue.
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UKUeE/2/embedded/result/).

Comment: Your demo appears to work as mine does. I can add new "objects" all day. I need to change a existing one.

Comment: In your code `X` is a local variable so once function is executed you cannot change X and it means you cant change the created balls. When you create balls store the variable `X` somewhere may be in an array and when you want to edit any property (color here) take out the reference from array and you `.attr` method.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
X.attr("fill", newColor);
```

Where `newColor` is the name of the variable you'd like to change its color to.

Comment: I thought that would work too, but the code tells me the 'X is undefined'. It appears that the object, using getElementById() appears to be 'a', but when I call a.attr it returns undefined.